# Trying to get the id of the last element in my json file through an api

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get the id of the last element in my json file through an api to be able to add an element without a random id , i want it to be like 1,2,3,4 etc... but i can't figure out how (i wana do that bc i can't use an id with letrers  ). Thank you in advance.

Comment: What API calls does your API provide? Is there a way to return the last element? If no, return all, sort by ID descending, grab the first element, return its index value.

Comment: i'm sorry but i'm kinda new to this (and english is not my native language) so i don't think i understand correctly what you're talking ab